# Count posts with php or store in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables:

#### forum

- id
- name
- description

#### posts

- id
- forumID
- body

What I wonder is should I create a field in forum where i store the number of posts that been made in that forum? Update it every time someone makes a post. or should I count them with php? Is it a huge performance difference?

Answer (score 3):

You should just query your posts table and count the posts with the forumID you want.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `posts` WHERE `forumID` = XX;
```

You should have an index on forumID anyway, since you will use it often in your queries. With that index, this query will run very, very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Small forum - not a big deal. But as your forum grows it will make a huge difference counting the number of posts in a simple query. The difference will be even more apparent if you store the posts in an innodb table instead of a myisam. So if you're not worried about it growing too big, use a query. Otherwise, add a column.

**Edit** - my advice? Save yourself the future headache and add a column.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's better using MySQL's `count()`, I don't think there's really a great difference in performance.

Answer (score 1):

The following query should be fast:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM posts
WHERE forumID = @forumID
```

You should make sure that there is an index on the forumID column so that it doesn't need to do a table scan.

Answer (score 1):

All in one shot:

```
SELECT post.forumID, forum.name, COUNT(post.forumId) as postCount
FROM post INNER JOIN forum ON post.forumId = forum.id 
GROUP BY post.forumID, forum.name
```

Answer (score 1):

To the questions "should I add a [counter] to my forum table" and "is there a huge performance difference" the answers are "yes" and "yes, if you have lots of messages." Even if you don't have tons of messages, I'd still recommend adding such a counter to your forum table.

Also, you should consider using a forum software instead of coding your own, because you'll encounter lots of that kind of dilemmas and you'll spend quite a lot of time rewriting stuff that already exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a cron script that calculates the `COUNT(*)` each hour or whenever an old post is deleted:

```
SET @mytime = CURRENT_TIME()

UPDATE  forums f
SET     post_count = 
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    posts p
        WHERE   p.forumID = f.id
                AND p.date <= @mytime
        ),
        count_updated = @mytime
```

, and `COUNT(*)` the new posts in a query:

```
SELECT  post_count +
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    posts p
        WHERE   forumID = f.id
                AND p.date > f.count_updated
        )
FROM    forums f
WHERE   f.id = @id
```

This is a good tradeoff between `UPDATE` overhead and `SELECT` overhead.